# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sound Design Stack Exchange](http://sound.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sound.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: am i seriously the only one doing this?

Comment: @ArnoudTraa, the site evaluation consists of reviewing 10 random questions and their answers.  If you go to the review queue, you'll see a new entry for site evaluation.  When the time period is over, the results will be displayed here.  In the past, this post has been used to discuss the results of the site-eval reviews.  Though, you can certainly post whatever you'd like.

Comment: thanks for letting me know how the evaluation works. however i was hoping to get some discussion going :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Sound Design depicting mental illness in film](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29769/sound-design-depicting-mental-illness-in-film)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does warm mean?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/what-does-warm-mean)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Compact high quality sound effects / ambience recording rig](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29793/compact-high-quality-sound-effects-ambience-recording-rig)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Video game music setup](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29834/video-game-music-setup)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Cutting diegetic SFX for 5.1 -- C or LR? (mono / stereo)](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29850/cutting-diegetic-sfx-for-5-1-c-or-lr-mono-stereo)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Reducing Noise in Feynman Lectures](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/reducing-noise-in-feynman-lectures)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How was this snare made?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29860/how-was-this-snare-made)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Prolems with mxl 770](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29830/prolems-with-mxl-770)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to create a transparent multiband splitter?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29954/how-to-create-a-transparent-multiband-splitter)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What is a "violator"?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29956/what-is-a-violator)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score 2):

I find it a little disconcerting that we have a couple questions reviewed with nearly equal parts *Excellent* and *Needs Improvement*

[How to create a transparent multiband splitter?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29954/how-to-create-a-transparent-multiband-splitter)

I'm just curious how this question needs improvement.  The OP accurately described...

- what was the goal,
- what had been tried,
- and a specific question.

Also, no matter how you word it, this questions appears at the top of the google search.

The question has attracted a better than average view/answer count.

It seems to me that this question is precisely what an *Excellent* question should be.

Comment: Well, I agree that the question is of high quality (I voted so in the eval). And I don't think that it's the case where the on-topicness is questionable, but maybe for some it is?

Comment: It's an excellent question, formatting and ideas are good. But is this a sound design question or a DSP engineering question? I don't really know actually. In other words: does it belong here? I think that's the reason some people will find a bad question, and that's also a reason why this way of 'self-evaluation' is only the start of a bigger evaluation "what is sound design stack exchange" about?

Comment: @ArnoudTraa I think it has nothing to do with DSP engineering. DSP engineering is lower level. Asker is not trying to code a splitter, but trying to use already existing tools to do the splitting. I honestly don't see why frequency splitting shouldn't be part of this site's scope. The question couldn't be more on-topic. The question and answers are useful and relevant for sound design in general. If anything it bothers me that such a relevant and useful question is being labeled as "possibly off-topic" or "possibly not good for this site".

Comment: @ArnoudTraa `what is sound design stack exchange about?` Why not "sound design in general"?

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say you guys have it ALL WRONG. The primary reason users signed up for the original SSD in the first place was because it was a gathering place for people who loved SOUND DESIGN. Not music production, not recording bands, not figuring out how to make Garage Band work, but SOUND DESIGN. And to focus it a bit more, SOUND DESIGN as it related to film, television, and occasionally theatre productions. THAT'S IT. We didn't want to discuss much past that. We loved talking about film sound, or how a particular sequence of a movie soundtrack moved us and motivated us to seek careers as sound designers. We fed off each other, we posted wide-open questions and expected wide-open answers. We were NOT RIGID. That's not how we operated. Anyone was free to ask, and anyone was free to answer. If we didn't like it, we downvoted like crazy, and hopefully the person that posted got the message. If we did like like, we upvoted like crazy and even more questions and comments were generated, spawning new threads and even private emails that resulting in actual, real-life meetings and job offers.

This SE is nothing like that. This SE is rigid, has a whole slew a newbie posts and is basically a site that, as a first time visitor seeking sound design inspiration, I would not choose to visit again.

I'm not here to offer suggestions - I already did that. I'm only posting to let you know that Arnoud is right and that the original spirit of SSD seems to be, once and for all, completely lost.

That's really sad.

Comment: It's done.  I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously my problem with some of the questions is that they're music related and not focussed on sound telling the story, example: how was this snare made.
Of course the answer is ok on that one, it's jus that it's only about 'a sound' not the function of the sound in a context.
This is what i feel sound design should be about. Hence our current discussions on what's on topic and what's not.

Comment: Sound synthesis is a huge part of sound design. How to build sounds, as in "how was this snare made", is as important as how sound is used to tell a story. Why restrict the scope of this SE only to only one fraction of sound design?

Comment: Please, tell how he tells the story with this snare?
First and foremost, it's a music production question.
And of course Sound Synthesis is a huge part of sound design. I've never claimed otherwise, what I'm saying is that in the snare example, there is no context besides the original song. The writer doesn't want anything other than to know how it's made. 
And even though that is not wrong to ask, I don't think it's very interesting for a sound design site, that is about sound design for media (film, games, installations etc).

Comment: There is no context because context is not needed for the question to be answered. The question will be interesting by its own merits, not unnecessary ones. I personally think it is a very interesting question. Difference in interests is expected in a heterogeneous community. Story telling is just one fraction of what sound design for media is. I don't think it's healthy to expect and suggest it to be part of %100 of the questions. If sound synthesis by itself will be on-topic, don't expect story telling to be part of it.

Comment: I guess your right about that, it doesn't have to be a 100%. But I'm getting a bit tired of new users that  have little idea what is on topic and ask things that have (imho) little relevance. At the moment nobody seems to really know what is on topic, I'm the only one trying to figure that out, it seems.. I don't want to be a hard ass on everyone.

Comment: Why not enlarge the scope? It's not like it will scare media sound designers out of here, and this SE could use some more users, visits, and activity in general. Maybe both parts (the one you consider off-topic and the one you are part of) can benefit from each other while staying relevant to sound design.

Comment: @JCPedroza "It's not like it will scare media sound designers out of here" well it did, and it does still. that's what i'm trying to halt

Comment: "Maybe both parts (the one you consider off-topic and the one you are part of) can benefit from each other while staying relevant to sound design." That would be great, but at the moment, I think that's not working very well..

Comment: Why would one part scare the other away? That doesn't make sense. They are both the same thing, just applied to different areas. Take Stack Overflow as example, there's room for many languages, paradigms, systems, etc. Functional Lisp math PhD programmers are not scaring Java systems programmers or C++ videogame programmers. Maybe you have the wrong perception of one side scaring the other, and what is really scaring people away is an overly and unnecessarily restricted scope. There's more than enough room for both (and more) sides.

Comment: "Maybe you have the wrong perception of one side scaring the other, and what is really scaring people away is an overly and unnecessarily restricted scope." 
Please don't say that, that's offensive to me. I have been around on SSD and stack exchange long enough to have a clear perception of it was and what i has become. I'm still here after the merge and I try to keep things clear and in focus, it's other people that left and if you read the meta discussions you will find them. I'm not saying there's no room for other opinions, I'm discussion the scope of the site. Let's keep it at that level.

Comment: Your longevity and experience don't make you immune to perception mistakes. What about the people leaving because of restrictions? Those won't leave a message here. Also, this meta is too small, I don't think it's safe to make it representative of what the  site really needs. It could be argued that those people fighting for a smaller scope were actually toxic for the site, and they leaving (along with implementation of a larger scope) will benefit this SE in the long run. I applaud your intentions and efforts, but I think they are not well focused. I'm discussing the scope of this site too.

Comment: Some users were indeed limiting the scope but the majority added a lot of experience and knowledge. So no, you're wrong, a limited scope helps create a better product/site than a too wide scope. In my experience that is what seperates a good idea from a bad. It's a natural part of a (design) process to exclude certain areas. Unfotunately, this is (again) no longer a constructive discussion, Your style doesn't feel like you want to discuss, but like want to pick a bone. I'm not into that, this place should not be about that. If you want to discuss on a normal level, you're welcome to meta. Bye

Comment: By adding a question instead of responding in this manner.

Comment: A limited scope helps, an overly limited scope is toxic. I think the participation, growth and activity of this SE is a good example. What worries me is that you seem to think that this site needs to be even more restrictive, while chances are that it needs the total opposite. I look at the bigger SEs and they all share scope with different approaches, and that induces activity, growth, and other positive and interesting dynamics. SO is not about only one paradigm, or one  language, or one system. Sound Design should be, in a similar way, about sound design in general, not only one side of it.

Comment: Also, I'm sorry if these comes as "bone picking", it wasn't my intention. I'm honestly interested in the discussion of why the site should be opposed on sound synthesis focused questions. It is nothing personal, and I don't think it had an offensive tone. If it did, I apologize.

Comment: @JCPedroza Reading all this gives me a clear impression that you missed what happened with the merge.  Arnoud is pretty spot on, and it's sad to see him get accosted for stepping up and working towards getting back the focus that so many of us enjoyed before the merge. I'm an electronic musician as well as a professional sound designer and like many, I loved SD being a place that was not overrun with "how  do you make this snare," even if I've answered a few. The broader scope that has occurred has killed this place and many amazing sound design professionals have given up on this place.

Comment: @JCPedroza  you see Jay's comment above?  You see his point status?

Comment: have a read:http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com/questions/196/what-happened-to-social-sound-design-again

Comment: mutiny on the mothership:http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com/questions/138/suggestion-split-sound-and-sound-design-in-two-sections

Comment: I think you are just new here. A quick read through meta will give you plenty of proof of what happened here. Numerous real professionals with vast amounts of knowledge are now gone because of the amount of off topic and uninteresting posts that have permeated this place. Part of the brilliance and success was the quality/quantity approach and narrow focus on Sound Design, not music production.

Comment: @Brad You just proved my point. There are not that many users complaining, and the few complaining are being overzealous. The lack of "interesting" questions comes from the side of the community that wants them. Also, there's not one single reason given to why other facets of sound design can't co-exist here other than "I don't want to read them". I'm sorry, but all I see is a very weak, broken, and flawed case here. I hope it all works for you guys.

Comment: @JCPedroza  have fun with your awesome forum about Garage Band.  I'm out.

Comment: @JCPedroza you have to understand that there majority of the guys that visited SSD probably have stopped using this site since the merge. The few who are left are still trying to bring back the first community sound designers worldwide could converse in. Obviously sound synthesis and music is part of sound design, but those are expected knowledge that a sound designer should have. 

We didn't need to talk about the simple stuff and could just go onto the things no one else was talking about. Design ideas, inspirations, workflows, technical expertise that was not shared elsewhere.

Comment: @takuya Why and how the existence of simple questions is preventing you from talking about the stuff you want? Look at other successful SEs, they don't limit their scope by expertise level. From beginners to masters they all coexist, and questions of all levels are welcome. There is more than enough room for everyone.

Comment: @takuya It seems that  what you guys really want and need is a forum, not a Q&A SE.

Comment: No @JCPedroza, what we wanted and what we needed was for StackExchange to leave SSD the hell alone and keep AVS to itself. I visited SSD multiple times a day, 5-6 days a week for 4 solid years. It was a niche website that catered to a very specific community. If we wanted to learn about programming drums or re-creating a synth stack, we'd go to a (**SHOCKER**) music production site.

Comment: SSD helped me grow my skills and personal network as an artistic professional. Since the merge I barely come by once a month because it's become nothing other than a source of anger, arguments and frustration rather than information and collaboration. I see that not much has changed in my absence.

Comment: @SteveUrban I'm watching the profiles of the people that are complaining of the lack of content, and all I'm seeing is that you guys are part of the problem not the solution. You specifically haven't asked a question since 2012. You ask for a dynamic that you are not contributing to. There is no reason why you shouldn't be asking what you consider interesting questions. Synthesis questions don't stop you from talking about something else. There is more than enough room for everyone, as other successful SEs have proven over and over again.

Comment: @SteveUrban Also, regarding this quote: `It was a niche website that catered to a very specific community.` That's exactly why you guys want and need a forum, not a SE Q&A. SEs are not for small niche communities. SEs seek growth, reach, visibility. This is not the place to carve such a restricted environment.

Comment: @JCPedroza We want what we had before the merge. The problem is not about packing up and moving on to somewhere else. The problem is we had a wealth of information on our old site that is now lost in the rubbish that fronts this SE site.
Like I've said many times before, one of the biggest draw for us at SSD were the more prolific and experienced contributors that frequented the forum. They were not your run of the mill professionals but the ones whose work we all respected and because of the site, were given access to their wisdom. You can't possibly replace that. And time has proven that too

Comment: @JCPedroza We aren't asking because we stopped thinking we would get the right answers. The qns on SE stay up for a day at most and then they get buried by the other qns. The qns that we asked often warranted answers and opinons by many many people. It's hard to do it in SE because of the nature of the site. You and the others use it to acquire quick answers while we wanted a variety of opinions.

Comment: @JCPedroza - just jumping in as an independent third party here (I was part of the AVP crowd, which had a VERY broad coverage before the merge).  The problem is signal to noise ratios.  If 95% of the questions on a site are simple, it isn't worth it for an expert to look through the 95% simple to find the 5% of questions that are actually interesting to them, so they just give up on the community entirely.  You can even see this at work on SO where people constantly want to get rid of "google search" questions and the like.  Good tag utilization can help on SO, but tags are less clear here.

Comment: You are correct that meta doesn't get enough activity to really be a solid indicator of community direction and I'm currently torn between the more basic crowd, which seems more active and seems to participate more than the old SSD crowd, but it can't be denied that the net impact is that many (almost all) of the experts that were involved with SSD were driven out because of the noise level from the merge and subsequent scope confusion.  (Which we haven't been able to fix for the aforementioned issue of user churn and lack of meta participation.)  That is a matter of site history fact.

Comment: The unknown in all of it is if it is a bigger loss to restrict the topic and push out active community members who are trying to get started (but may result in a shallower site that can't answer deeper questions) or to block out those surface level questions (and prevent some newcomers to the field from being able to participate), but reduce noise to make it friendlier to what experts were using in SSD.  I'm honestly not sure which is the best choice for the site at this point, so I've mostly been waiting and watching.

Comment: @Takuya - that's the point of tags.  If nobody bothers to ask the questions you find interesting, then there is nothing to be answered and you can't reform the community.  Make a tag that fits those questions if there isn't one already, start asking questions in that tag and favorite the tag so that it keeps them on your front page.  Then you can have that prolonged uptime.  Also, as long as people are making contributions, it will still stay up on the front for anyone that uses the active posts view, which is what most users interested in answers from multiple people view in.

Comment: If everyone sits around waiting for someone else to start asking the questions you want, you are never going to get them no matter what we do.  My main reason for being more open to the more basic questions is the lack of anyone showing interest in asking deeper questions, which leads me to believe there just aren't that many of them to generate regular interaction.  That could be wrong, but without people posting them, I have nothing else to go on, and I'm very hard pressed to shut down a growing community of people actually asking and answering questions for a group that isn't asking any.

Comment: Also, since this is getting rather long, I've made a chat room to continue the discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/17591/scope-discussion?tab=general) if people want to.  Please remember to keep it civil though.  Frustration is obviously getting high on both sides.

Comment: The name is part of the problem.  'Sound Design' as a term is applicable to modern music production just the same as it is applicable to stage/film/post work.  The title makes no distinction.  You can complain all you like about if this is a proper use of the term but the fact remains that 'sound design' as a term has been appropriated by modern music production.  The volume of 'music' oriented questions here is proof of that.